# peer-to-peer Networking iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am new to networking over iOS and i am having a lot of difficulty in finding a good tutorial to learn about it. I am making a game and implemented it for a single player but now i have to make it multiplayer. What i have to do on server is only comparing the final score of the two players playing the game and display the message that who won the game. There are no asynchronous calls required the final score is only needed when the timer ends and reach 0. Please help me with for a kick start,  really need it. I have been scratching my head over bonjour but unable to understand it as i am very new to networking.

Comment: Check `Game Center`. it has this provision

Comment: I notice you have not accepted any answers for questions you've asked. Please go back and accept answers if the question has been answered or you risk people ignoring your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multipeer Connectivity will work if all players are in close proximity or on the same network. However since you did not specify that those conditions would necessarily be met, you probably want to look at the Game Center networking functionality at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html